# Using Ledger with node to bake

Tags: baking, node, ledger

I have imported secret key and can see known address. However, this is where the instructions become clear as mud. I used [this guide](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos/blob/master/README.md). My node was built from source on MacOs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you be more specific on things you had tried and what guide you used? the question is super vague, it'll be very hard to help you properly.

Answer (score 3):

## Authorize ledger for baking

This will allow the ledger to sign operation without "human interaction" each time.

```
$ tezos-client setup ledger to bake for <ALIAS>
```

## Register as delegate

This is how you register as a baker on the network.

```
$ tezos-client register key <ALIAS> as delegate
```